# correct comparison between post and table column value does not show right echo

Tags: php, html, sql

Here is my rundown on what the codes should do:

- retrieve the (POST) value of a text field
- search a database column for a "promo code" that matches with the input
- if a match is found, echo 'No coupon code exists!';
- the "used" column of the matched code will turn from 0 to 1

so far, my if statement always just goes directly to the part where a match is not found even if there is, thereby showing only "echo 'Coupon code does not exist!';"

[image: not existing]

here is the table (named "promocode_3")

[image]

I started with a function:
(PromoCode.mc.php)

```
<?php
 Class PromoCode_MC {

    function getCoupons() { 
    global $db;
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM promocode_3 WHERE `used` = 0");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchall();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} } } ?>
```

then id call the function from a different file
(membership.vc.php)

```
require_once($routePath . "_mc/PromoCode.mc.php");
$mcPromoCode = new PromoCode_MC();
$coupons = $mcPromoCode->getCoupons();
```

finally my third file will get the function and show the echo
(membership.php)

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('membership.vc.php');
?>

          <form method="post">
            <input type="text"id ="lux_code" name="lux_code"  placeholder="ENTER PROMO CODE" style="text-align:center;" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="submit" class="full_width btn color-white mwc-orange-background-color" name="redeem" value="REDEEM">
          </form>

          <?php

            $coupons = ['coupon_code'];

            if (isset($_POST['redeem']) && $_POST['redeem'] == 'REDEEM'){

            $couponCode = $_POST['lux_code'];
            $match = false;
            foreach($coupons as $coupon){

                if($coupon == $couponCode) { //check to see if posted value matches

                    $match = true;
                    echo 'Coupon code exists!';
                    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE coupons SET used = '1' WHERE p3id = :p3id");
                    $stmt2->execute(array(
                        ':p3id'=>$coupon['p3id']
                    ));

                    break;

                } else {
                  echo 'Coupon code does not exist!';
                }

            }
          }
           ?>
```

any help to find the error would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE:

even when i just tried to straight up echo based on comparison, i still dont get a 'echo Coupon code exists!'; if i type in a string value that SHOULD match with one of the coupon_code columns in the table

```
            if (isset($_POST['redeem']) && $_POST['redeem'] == 'REDEEM'){

            $couponCode = $_POST['lux_code'];
            foreach($coupons as $coupon){

                if($coupon == $couponCode) { //check to see if posted value matches

                    echo 'Coupon code exists!';


                } else {
                  echo 'Coupon code does not exist!';
                }

            }
          }
```

Comment: $couponCode should be a string because it came from the input textfield "lux_code"

Comment: `':p3id'=>$coupon['p3id']` so here, `$coupon` shouldn't be an array right?

Comment: $coupon is 'coupon_code' and as seen from my table, its a string

Comment: so `':p3id'=>$coupon['p3id']` is wrong correct?

Comment: that or something else since theres no correct output

Comment: even if i took out that out and just left "echo" there is still no effect

Comment: Yeah because that stuff only happens in the true portion of the if statement and your code is always hitting the false portion

Comment: can you please expand on that?

Comment: You need to debug your code. add `var_dump($coupon);` inside your foreach loop. add `var_dump($couponCode);` before your foreach loop. Also use `strcmp` not `==` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php